# Custom JQuery Plugin Method error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been working on writing a custom jquery plugin for one of my web applications but I've been running into a strange error, I think it's due to my unfamiliarity with object-oriented programming.

The bug that I've been running into comes when I try to run the $(".list-group").updateList('template', 'some template') twice, the first time it works just fine, but the second time I run the same command, I get an object is not a function error.  Here's the plugin code:

```
(function($){
    defaultOptions = {
        defaultId: 'selective_update_',
        listSelector: 'li'
    };

    function UpdateList(item, options) {
        this.options = $.extend(defaultOptions, options);
        this.item = $(item);
        this.init();
        console.log(this.options);
    }
    UpdateList.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            console.log('initiation');
        },
        template: function(template) {
            // this line is where the errors come
            this.template = template;
        },
        update: function(newArray) {
            //update code is here
            // I can run this multiple times in a row without it breaking
        }
    }

    // jQuery plugin interface
    $.fn.updateList = function(opt) {
        // slice arguments to leave only arguments after function name
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this.each(function() {
            var item = $(this), instance = item.data('UpdateList');
            if(!instance) {
                // create plugin instance and save it in data
                item.data('UpdateList', new UpdateList(this, opt));
            } else {
                // if instance already created call method
                if(typeof opt === 'string') {
                    instance[opt](args);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

One thing I did notice when I went to access this.template - It was in an array so I had to call this.template[0] to get the string...I don't know why it's doing that, but I suspect it has to do with the error I'm getting. Maybe it can assign the string the first time, but not the next? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: What line of code is the error associated with?

Comment: When I call my plugin with the 'template' input twice (to call that function) I get the error, I've isolated it (I think) to the line this.template = template;

Comment: that line wouldn't cause a `object is not a function error`

Comment: Error messages usually have lines of code associated with them in the browser console. The most likely cause of the error, I think, is `instance[opt](args)` - put a `console.log("opt is " + opt)` before that line.

Comment: Also probably be good to add `console.dir(instance);` there too.

Comment: normally they do have a line associated! but this time it didn't :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.template = template
```

Is in fact your problem, as you are overwriting the function that is set on the instance. You end up overwriting it to your `args` array as you pass that as your argument to the initial `template` function. It basically will do this:

```
this.template = ["some template"];
```

Thus the next time `instance[opt](args)` runs it will try to execute that array as if it were a function and hence get the not a function error.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vho6oad/1/)

Comment: thanks this is it! definitely did not realize my naming was not the smartest haha